# Read from one DB table and it to another ASP.NET using foreach statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to read datas from one database table and then add it to another table. This is my example and code.

This is the table I am reading from:
[image]

And this is the table when I save it:

[image]

This is the code I use:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var db = Database.Open("ConnectionString");
        var FJSCR = db.Query("SELECT * FROM [SALESAGENT]");

        foreach (var item in FJSCR)
        {
            Label1.Text += item.CODE;
            //Label1.Text += "<hr/>";

            try
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
                con .Open();
                string FJ = "EXEC sp_msforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all'";
                FJ = "insert into MAG(COD) VALUES (@COD)";
                SqlCommand kom = new SqlCommand(FJ, con);
                kom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COD", Label1.Text);
                kom.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write("Error " + ex.ToString());
            }
        }  
    }
```

Any help? Thank You!

Comment: So what you want to achieve ?

Comment: Is that repeated Data is Problem ?

Comment: @user2767299 , I want to add the datas from the first picture to another table which is the second picture.

Comment: @Grant Winney , Nope, just as-is. I want this way. This is the way I was requested to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just straight away COPY the data from one table to another, no need to use label in between.

just change ;

```
kom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COD", Label1.Text);
```

To

```
kom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COD", item.CODE);
```

OR

If you want to use LABEL then GET New record value in label every time, Do not APPEND;

In that case, replace;

```
 Label1.Text += item.CODE;
```

TO

```
 Label1.Text = item.CODE;
```

Hope this is what you are looking for..!!!

Comment: Tried the first one. It worked. Thanks a lot. You saved me. :D